# ML.Net Multiple Prediction

Tags: c#, ml.net

I did exactly as this documentation says

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/machine-learning/how-to-guides/machine-learning-model-predictions-ml-net

I have this code to predict multiple input data (ML.Net 1.7)

```
var predEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ClusterData,
                                        SentimentPrediction>(model);
var batchData = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(listBatch);
IDataView predictions = model.Transform(batchData);

// Get Predictions
float[] scoreColumn = predictions.GetColumn<float>("Score").ToArray();
```

And I get this error in the last line:

```
 error CS1061: 'IDataView' does not contain a definition for 'GetColumn' and 
 no accessible extension method 'GetColumn' accepting a first argument of type 'IDataView'
 could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Comment: The [documentation of IDataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.ml.idataview?view=ml-dotnet) does not contain any method GetColumn, therefore the compiler error is right.
But its property Schema is of type Microsoft.ML.DataViewSchema contains a method GetColumnOrNull

Answer (score 1):

It means that the code is trying to call the GetColumn method on an instance of the IDataView type, but the method doesn't exist.

To resolve the issue, you should:

1. Make sure you have the necessary using directive or assembly reference.
2. Check if the correct version of the Microsoft.ML.Data library is referenced in your project.
3. Make sure the column you're trying to access actually exists in the data view.